# Draw a line in LibGdx that passes for a certain point

Tags: java, libgdx

In LibGdx there's a really easy way to draw shapes, currently I'm drawing lines like this:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

There's a defined starting and final point, let's call them point 1 and point 2, respectively. I need to draw a line that starts in point 1, pass point 2 and continues in the same direction, like this:

[image]

Any ideas how can this be done?

Comment: And where does it end? The screen edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have two vectors representing your two points:

```
Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(x1, y1);
Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(x2, y2);
```

Then what you want to do can be achieved by simply doing that:

```
Vector2 p3 = new Vector2(p2).sub(p1).add(p2);

shapeRenderer.line(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y);
```

You can change the distance between `p2` and `p3` by using the `scl()` method when computing `p3`:

```
Vector2 p3 = new Vector2(p2).sub(p1).scl(0.5f).add(p2);
```

For example if you use `scl(1f)` or don't use it at all like in the previous code snippet, distance between `p2` and `p3` will be the same as between `p1` and `p2`. If you call `scl(0.5f)` length will be divided by 2, etc.